# What is the best way to match over 10000 different elements in database?

Tags: java, mysql, database

Ok here's my scenario:

Programming language:  Java

I have a `MYSQL` database which has around 100,000,000 entries.

I have a a list of values in memory say `valueList` with around 10,000 entries.

I want to iterate through `valueList` and check whether each value in this list, has  a match in the database.

This means I have to make atleast 10,000 database calls which is highly inefficient for my application.
Other way would be to load the entire database into memory once, and then do the comparison in the memory itself. This is fast but needs a huge amount of memory.

Could you guys suggest a better approach for this problem?

**EDIT :**

Suppose valueList consists of values like :
`{"New","York","Brazil","Detroit"}`

From the database, I'll have a match for `Brazil` and `Detroit`. But not for `New` and `York` , though `New York` would have matched. So the next step is , in case of any remaining non matched  values, I combine them to see if they match now. So In this case, I combine `New` and `York` and then find the match.

In the approach I was following before( one by one database call) , this was possible. But in case of the approach of creatign a temp table, this wont be possible

Comment: Insert the data in a temporary table with one insert. Then join to get the result.

Comment: Break it into 1000 or lower chunks and run an IN statement...

Comment: Ok @juergend has a better solution :-)

Comment: Ok my bad for using too much oracle, if anyone is thinking there's no need to chunk 10k items into smaller one in MySQL, that's an Oracle limitation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could insert the 10k records in a temporary table with a single insert like this

```
insert into tmp_table (id_col)
values (1),
       (3),
       ...
       (7);
```

Then join the the 2 tables to get the desired results.

I don't know your table structure, but it could be like this

```
select s.* 
from some_table s
inner join tmp_table t on t.id_col = s.id
```

Comment: Great approach. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting the 10k data in the first place? From the DB too?

Comment: Actually that 10k data is a list of tokens. The token is derived from a text file in the program. Your approach works for 80% of the cases. I will edit the question to included the 20% of cases ...See if you can find any approach for that.

Comment: MySQL has a way to insert csv data directly into a table with a bulk insert. Maybe that is the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks, I solved that issue by using `LIKE` instead of equals and then performing some logic. Your approach helped a lot!